# Google Nearby for Android multi-peer connection without Google Play Services installed

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I'm currently working on an app which works with multi-peer connectivity between a few Android devices. One of the libraries that allows to do such thing is a recent [Nearby](https://developers.google.com/nearby) library from Google. The devices have 26 API level.

However, it requires Google Play Services installed on target device. The devices to which the app will be shipped to don't have Google Play Services installed. And, unfortunately, using something like MicroG is not an option for my case, as it potentially violates safety requirement put on my project.

Has anybody found a way to use the Nearby library on devices without Google Play Services installed?

And if you have any good alternatives for multi-peer connectivity data transfer, please, suggest them, I'll be glad to hear about them.

Thank you for your time and help!